# How can I ensure an API call response completes before an operation in Blazor WASM

Tags: asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I've scoured stackoverflow looking for ways to make synchronous API calls in Blazor WASM, and come up empty.  The rest is a fairly length explanation of why I think I want to achieve this, but since Blazor WASM runs single-threaded, all of the ways I can find to achieve this are out of scope.  If I've missed something or someone spots a better approach, I sincerely appreciate the effort to read through the rest of this...

I'm working on a Blazor WASM application that targets a GraphQL endpoint.  Access to the GraphQL endpoint is granted by passing an appropriate Authorization JWT which has to be refreshed at least every 30 minutes from a login API.  I'm using a 3rd party GraphQL library (strawberry-shake) which utilizes the singleton pattern to wrap an HttpClient that is used to make all of the calls to the GraphQL endpoint.  I can configure the HttpClient using code like this:

```
builder.Services
.AddFxClient() // strawberry-shake client
.ConfigureHttpClient((sp, client) =>
{
    client.BaseAddress =
            new Uri(
                "https://[application url]/graphql");  // GraphQL endpoint
    var token = "[api token]"; // token retrieved from login API
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
});
```

The trick now is getting the API token from the login API at least every 30 minutes.  To accomplish this, I created a service that tracks the age of the token and gets a new token from the login API when necessary.  Pared down, the essential bits of the code to get a token look like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    if ((_expirationDateTime ?? DateTime.Now).AddSeconds(-300) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        try
        {
            var jwt = new
            {
                token =
                    "[custom JWT for login API validation]"
            };

            var payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jwt);
            var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var postResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://[login API url]/login", content);
            var responseString = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _accessToken = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthenticationResponse>(responseString).access_token;
            _expirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1800);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    return _accessToken;
}
```

So, now I need to wire this up to the code which configures the HttpClient used by the GraphQL service.  This is where I'm running into trouble.  I started with code that looks like this:

```
// Add login service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<FxAuthClient>();

// Wire up GraphQL client
builder.Services
    .AddFxClient()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(async (sp, client) =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress =
                new Uri(
                    "https://[application url]/graphql");
        var token = await sp.GetRequiredService<FxAuthClient>().GetAccessToken();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    });
```

This "works" when the application is loaded [somewhat surprisingly, since notice I'm not "await"ing the GetAccessToken()].  But the behavior if I let the 30 minute timer run out is that the first attempt I make to access the GraphQL endpoint uses the expired token and not the new token.  I can see that GetAccessToken() refreshes expired token properly, and is getting called every time I utilize the FxClient, but except for the first usage of FxClient, the GetAccessToken() code actually runs after the GraphQL request.  So in essence, it always uses the previous token.

I can't seem to find anyway to ensure that GetAccessToken() happens first, since in Blazor WASM you are confined to a single thread, so all of the normal ways of enforcing synchronous behavior fails, and there isn't an asynchronous way to configure the FxClient's HttpClient.

Can anyone see a way to get this to work?  I'm thinking I may need to resort to writing a wrapper around the strawberry FxClient, or perhaps an asynchronous extension method that wraps the ConfigureHttpClient() function, but so far I've tried to avoid this [mostly because I kept feeling like there must be an "easier" way to do this].  I'm wondering if anyone knows away to force synchronous behavior of the call to the login API in Blazor WASM, sees another approach that would work, or can offer any other suggestion?

Lastly, it occurs to me that it might be useful to see a little more detail of the ConfigureHttpClient method.  It is autogenerated, so I can't really change it, but here it is:

```
public static IClientBuilder<T> ConfigureHttpClient<T>(
    this IClientBuilder<T> clientBuilder,
    Action<IServiceProvider, HttpClient> configureClient,
    Action<IHttpClientBuilder>? configureClientBuilder = null)
    where T : IStoreAccessor
{
    if (clientBuilder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientBuilder));
    }

    if (configureClient == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configureClient));
    }

    IHttpClientBuilder builder = clientBuilder.Services
        .AddHttpClient(clientBuilder.ClientName, (sp, client) =>
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(
                new ProductInfoHeaderValue(
                    new ProductHeaderValue(
                        _userAgentName,
                        _userAgentVersion)));
            configureClient(sp, client);
        });

    configureClientBuilder?.Invoke(builder);

    return clientBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Trying to make it sync (non-async) is fruitless, because there only is one thread there is no API that will let you block that thread. All I/O must be async.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer but sticking this inside the ClientBuilder doesn't look right. You probably need something with a MessageHandler. Like `builder.Services.AddHttpClient(...)
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyAuthorizationMessageHandler>();`